# Duplicate detection + create new column with dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to automate my data cleaning process. My dataset looks like this:

`ADDRESS             PHONE    TYPE
123 Willow Street   7429947  RESIDENTIAL
123 Willow Street   7426629  RESIDENTIAL
234 Butter Road     7564123  RESIDENTIAL`

It's quite large - several hundred thousand rows. I'd like to be able to do the following thing:

(1) Duplicate Detection, so I can eliminate the "nearly"-duplicate rows.
(2) Create a new column for the non-duplicated data - something like PHONE 2. The issue is that I cannot know beforehand whether or not there are only 2 duplicate rows - could be *n*.

The outcome would hopefully be something like this:

`ADDRESS             PHONE   PHONE 2    TYPE
123 Willow Street   7429947  7426629    RESIDENTIAL
234 Butter Road     7564123             RESIDENTIAL`

I'd love to do this with dplyr, but I'm sort of at a loss as to where to start. Any pointers?

Comment: What is the expected output in the above case? Which row do you keep? What makes something a prospective duplicate?

Comment: @Gopala - Thanks - I edited to include an expected output.

Comment: Is phone the only column to handle? What if the address is slightly different? Your question / requirement is still not clear.

Comment: @Gopala - The only value that may be different is in the PHONE column. Address/Type will always be consistent - just duplicated rows may exist because of the different value for PHONE.

Comment: This looks like a reshape wide to me. Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format) for other options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a combination of `dplyr` and `tidyr`, you can do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df <- data.frame(ADDRESS = c('123 Willow Street', '123 Willow Street',
                             '234 Butter Road'),
                 PHONE = c('7429947', '7426629', '7564123'),
                 TYPE = 'RESIDENTIAL', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df %>%
  group_by(ADDRESS, TYPE) %>%
  mutate(PHONEID = paste0('PHONE', row_number())) %>%
  spread(PHONEID, PHONE)
```

Output will be as follows:

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 4]
Groups: ADDRESS, TYPE [2]

            ADDRESS        TYPE  PHONE1  PHONE2
*             <chr>       <chr>   <chr>   <chr>
1 123 Willow Street RESIDENTIAL 7429947 7426629
2   234 Butter Road RESIDENTIAL 7564123    <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a great start. Much appreciated.